# C iterate array by known sizeof

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, sizeof

I'm trying to make a small library for particle management that allows to "expand" struct with user's data (texture, animation frames, etc). The library would know only the size of the expanded struct.
How do I iterate through the array of unknown struct types but known size of a struct?

```
typedef struct{
    int type;
}Base;

typedef struct{
    Base base;
    int value;
}inherited;

int main(){
    size_t size = sizeof(inherited);
    int count = 10;
    
    void *b = malloc(size * count);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        // iterate based on known size & send to callback
        callback( &( (size)b )[i] );
    }
    
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"How do I iterate through the array of unknown struct types but known size of a struct?"* - if you don't know the type then you don't even know the size, do ya? Either you know both or you know none of the two.

Comment: Why don't your use a pointer to `inherited`?  `inherited *p = malloc(size * count);` With this pointer you address each array item with `callback(&p[i]);` .

Comment: What's the prototype of `callback`?

Comment: Replace: callback( &( (size)b )[i] ); with callback(b + (i * size) );

Comment: Is there supposed to be another function that takes a `void *` as a parameter that runs through the loop?

Comment: @SPlatten Your advice will work only after changing the `b` declaration from `void*` to `char*`. The `void` type has no size, so `void*` can't be used in pointer arithmetics.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli there is 100 and more ways to get to know the size. User will provide the size of the extended struct and BAM I have the size.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Because as I wrote in the question - type is unknown, known is only base struct and users implemented structs size.
The callback is irrelevant in this question and it's here for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Related: maybe `typedef struct{ int type; size_t size; }Base;` isn't such a bad idea?

Comment: @SPlatten your proposed solution will iterate through array as if elements are sizeof(void).

Comment: @dbush That is a solution but I want to avoid asking the user to create an iterator.

Comment: @NeZvers What I mean is something like the answer from Ian Abbott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *b = malloc(size * count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    // iterate based on known size & send to callback
    callback( b + i * size );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the most correct and compact answer I needed.

Comment: It would work better if instead of using a char* and then size, you create a structure that is the same size as 'size' and then you can use that.

Comment: @SPlatten no it will not.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the code that does the `malloc` and calls `callback` doesn't know anything about the type of the object, only its size.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *alloc_and_init(size_t nmemb, size_t size, void (*callback)(void *))
{
    void *b = calloc(nmemb, size);
    if (b)
    {
        char *p = b;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
        {
            callback(p);
            p += size;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

typedef struct{
    int type;
}Base;

typedef struct{
    Base base;
    int value;
}inherited;

void init_inherited(void *p)
{
    inherited *obj = p;
    /* do initialization of obj->* here */
}

int main(void)
{
    int objcount = 10;
    inherited *objarr;

    objarr = alloc_and_init(objcount, sizeof(*objarr),
                            init_inherited);
    /* ... */
    free(objarr);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the perfect answer. I needed the only solution for the interaction but the solution is loud and clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
for( inherited *p = b, *e = p + count; p < e; p++ ){
    callback(p);
}
```

Comment: The inherited type is unknown, only base struct and sizeof(Inherited). Ian gave the perfect solution to cast into char and iterate by (i * size).

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism in C is always rather clunky. Basically you have to construct a "vtable" manually. The naive, simplified version below lets each object have its own function pointer. You'll end up with something rather contrived like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct base_t base_t;
typedef void callback_t (const base_t* arg);

struct base_t
{
  int type;
  callback_t* callback;
};

typedef struct
{
  base_t base;
  int value;
} inherited_t;


void callback_base (const base_t* arg)
{
  puts(__func__);
}

void callback_inherited (const base_t* arg)
{
  const inherited_t* iarg = (const inherited_t*)arg;
  printf("%s value: %d\n", __func__, iarg->value);
  
}

int main (void)
{
  // allocate memory
  base_t* array [3] = 
  {
    [0] = malloc(sizeof(inherited_t)),
    [1] = malloc(sizeof(base_t)),
    [2] = malloc(sizeof(inherited_t)),
  };

  // initialize objects
  *(inherited_t*)array[0] = (inherited_t){ .base.callback=callback_inherited, .value = 123 };
  *(array[1]) = (base_t){ .callback=callback_base };
  *(inherited_t*)array[2] = (inherited_t){ .base.callback=callback_inherited, .value = 456 };
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    array[i]->callback(array[i]); // now we get polymorphism here
  }
}
```

A more professional version involves writing a translation unit (.h + .c) per "class" and then combine allocation with initialization in the "constructor". It would be implemented with opaque type, see [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888) Inside the constructor, set the vtable corresponding to the type of object allocated.

I'd also boldly claim that any OO solution using `void*` arguments has some design flaw. The interface should be using the base class pointer. Void pointers are dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your version, but it is too overkill. Ian Abbott posted the perfect solution. I just need to have a char pointer and iterate with (i * size).